# How to save a existing file with some changes made in the textarea?

Tags: php

In my project,when read button is pressed,the content of the file should  be loaded into the textarea,then users will make changes on that text then they should save the changes of that file by clicking save button...The problem is I can open my file into the textarea but could not to save it.please have a look at my code and answer me

Here is my code:

netcodetesting.php

```
    <html>
   <head>


<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleee.css" />
<script src="basicbutton.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include('insert.php');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","abcde","dfdfdfdfdfd","mysql");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email_address']);


$r= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM o_assignment where email_address='$email'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['home_directory']);
$file= "$filename";


if(isset($_POST['text1'])){
$file_open = fopen($file,"a+"); 
fwrite($file_open, $_POST['text1']);
fclose($file_open);
mysqli_close($con);
}

?> 


<form name="form1" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method ="POST" >
<button title="bold" onclick="mod_selection('\\bf{','}')" type="button"><b>B</b></button>
<button title="italic" onclick="mod_selection('\\it{','}')" type="button"><i>I</i></button>
<button title="underline" onclick="mod_selection('\\ul{','}')" type="button"><u>U</u></button>
<button title="subscript" onclick="mod_selection('\sub{','}')" type="button"><sub>subscript</sub></button>
<button title="subscript" onclick="mod_selection('\sup{','}')" type="button"><sup>supscript</sup></button>

<button title="undo" onmousedown="undo(document.form1.text1);" type="button">undo</button>
<button title="redo" onmousedown="redo(document.form1.text1);" type="button">redo</button>
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="eraseText('my_text');"> 
<input type="button" value="read" onclick="clientSideInclude('my_text','<?php echo openingfile(); ?>')"/>

    <input type="submit" value="save"/> 


 </br> <textarea  class="text_edit" name="text1"  id="my_text" onkeydown="countclik(document.form1.text1);" ></textarea></br></form>


</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

function openingfile(){
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","abcde","dfdfdfdfdfd","mysql");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email_address']);


$r= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM o_assignment where email_address='$email'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $row['home_directory']);
$file= "$filename";
echo $file;


mysqli_close($con);

}

?>
```

login.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="netcodetesting.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"></br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password"></br>
Email-Address: <input type="text" name="email_address"></br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

basicbutton.js

```
function clientSideInclude(id, url) {
  var req = false;
  // For Safari, Firefox, and other non-MS browsers
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    try {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
      catch (e) {
      req = false;
        }
  } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // For Internet Explorer on Windows
    try {
      req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {
      try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
            catch (e) {
            req = false;
            }
        }
  }
 var element = document.getElementById(id);
 var str = "";
 if (!element) {
  alert("Bad id " + id + 
   "passed to clientSideInclude." +
   "You need a div or span element " +
   "with this id in your page.");
  return;
 }
  if (req) {
    // Synchronous request, wait till we have it all
    req.open('GET', url, false);
    req.send(null);
    str = req.responseText;
    str=str.replace(/\\&#39;/g,"'");
    str=str.replace(/\\'/g,"'");
    str=str.replace(/\\"/g,'"');
    str=str.replace(/\\\\/g,'\\');
    str=str.replace(/\\0/g,'\0');
  element.innerHTML = str;
  } else {
    element.innerHTML =
   " -- ";
  }
```

what is the mistake in my code?why the file is not get saved after the changes has made??

Comment: You're missing a quote in `mysqli_connect("localhost","abcde",dfdfdfdfdfd","mysql");` and your SQL code is prone to SQL injections, please use the according methods to use user input as SQL parameters.

Comment: I edited that mistake..actually the problem is not with mysql,its getting connected but the file is not getting saved